# O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde tenho a classe Paciente herdando da classe Usuário e estou usando o Entity Framework para mapear as tabelas do banco de dados por tipo (TPT), quando tento acessa pelo navegador a View de classe Paciente tenho o seguinte erro:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Projeto.Models.Usuario]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Projeto.Models.Paciente]'.

Classe Usuário:

```
public  class Usuario : RepositorioBase<Usuario>, IUsuario

{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public bool Ativio { get; set; }

}
```

Classe Paciente:

```
 public class Paciente : Usuario
    {

        public string Apelido { get; set; }

        public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Contexto:

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public PepContext()
            : base("Context")
        {


        }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PacienteConfiguration());


        }
}
```

PacienteConfiguration:

```
public class PacienteConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Paciente>
    {
        public PacienteConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Pacientes");
        }
    }
```

Model da View da classe Paciente:

```
@model IEnumerable<Projeto.Models.Paciente>
```

Controller:

```
 public class PacienteController : Controller
    {
        readonly Paciente _paciente;

        public PacienteController(Paciente paciente)
        {
            _paciente = paciente;
        }

        // GET: Paciente
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var paciente = _paciente.GetAll();
            return  View(paciente);
        }

        // GET: Paciente/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var paciente = _paciente.GetById(id);
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Paciente/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Paciente/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Paciente paciente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _paciente.Add(paciente);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(paciente);
        }

        // GET: Paciente/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var paciente = _paciente.GetById(id);
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Paciente/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Paciente paciente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _paciente.Update(paciente);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(paciente);
        }

        // GET: Paciente/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var paciente = _paciente.GetById(id);
            return View(paciente);
        }

        // POST: Paciente/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var paciente = _paciente.GetById(id);
            _paciente.Remove(paciente);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sua view espera um `Enumerable()` de paciente mas você está passando uma lista de Usuario. Poste o seu `Controller` para vermos como está o seu retorno.

Comment: @Randrade meu _Controller_ é esse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque não é possível converter um List no tipo IEnumerable de forma implícita.
Você deve alterar o seu método Paciente.GetAll (convertendo o retorno do tipo List para IEnumerable) ou o tipo do model (IEnumerable para List) na sua view.

Veja abaixo:

Alteração no método GetAll:

```
    var pacientes = pacienteDb.ListarPacientes()
    return pacientes.AsEnumerable();
```

Ou alterar o model da view para o tipo List:

```
    @model List<Projeto.Models.Paciente>
```

Comment: Alterei o método GetAll mas deu o mesmo erro, alterei o model para list deu o seguinte erro:     **'List<Paciente>' does not contain a definition for 'Matricula' and no extension method 'Matricula' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Paciente>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Comment: Nesse caso recomendo você a criar uma _ViewModel_, pois o binding dos campos é feito em cima da classe colocada como argumento, e ela não entende herança. Por isso você não encontra a propriedade Matricula.

Comment: Vou seguir suas orientações, obrigado

Comment: Preciso mapeando uma Model de domínio para uma View Model, é isso ?

Comment: Isso. De uma olhada no AutoMapper  http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-utilizando-automapper-com-view-model-pattern/  e  https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Ok, mais uma dúvida rsrs, a classe **PacienteViewModel** precisa herdar da classe **Usuario** ?

Comment: Não. Ela deve conter todos os campos de Paciente e Usuário.

Comment: Ok, obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66562/discussion-between-alerf-morais-and-d-aguilar).